# Морской бой с++ winforms. Не получается сделать чтобы клетки вокруг корабля закрашивались когда корабль полностью сбит

Tags: c++-cli

```
private: System::Void ris() {
    SolidBrush^ mySolidBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Red);
    Graphics^ formGraph4 = this->panel1->CreateGraphics();
    Graphics^ formGraph5 = this->panel2->CreateGraphics();
    Brush^ Заливка = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Orange);
    //formGraph4->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Blue),0,0,200,200);
    for (int ix = 1; ix <= 10; ix++) {
        for (int iy = 1; iy <= 10; iy++) {
            bool isShipSunk = true;
            switch (mas[ix][iy]) {
            case 1:
                formGraph4->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black), (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20, 20, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                formGraph4->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Red), (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20, 20, 20);
                formGraph4->DrawLine(Pens::Black, (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20, (ix - 1) * 20 + 20, (iy - 1) * 20 + 20);
                formGraph4->DrawLine(Pens::Black, (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20 + 20, (ix - 1) * 20 + 20, (iy - 1) * 20);

                // Проверяем, потоплен ли корабль
```

// Проверяем, потоплен ли корабль
// Проверяем, потоплен ли корабль

```
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                        if (mas[i][j] == 2 && mas2[i][j] != 2) {
                            isShipSunk = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isShipSunk) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Если корабль полностью потоплен, закрашиваем клетки вокруг него точками
                if (isShipSunk) {
                    for (int i = ix - 1; i <= ix + 1; i++) {
                        for (int j = iy - 1; j <= iy + 1; j++) {
                            if (i >= 1 && i <= 10 && j >= 1 && j <= 10 && mas[i][j] != 2 && mas2[i][j] != 2) {
                                mas2[i][j] = 2;
                                formGraph4->FillEllipse(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black), (i - 1) * 20 + 8, (j - 1) * 20 + 8, 4, 4);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



                break;



            case 3:
                formGraph4->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black), (ix - 1) * 20 + 8, (iy - 1) * 20 + 8, 4, 4);

                break;
            }
            switch (mas2[ix][iy]) {
                /*case 1:
                    formGraph5->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black),(ix-1)*20,(iy-1)*20,20,20);
                break;*/
            case 2:
                formGraph5->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Red), (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20, 20, 20);
                formGraph5->DrawLine(Pens::Black, (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20, (ix - 1) * 20 + 20, (iy - 1) * 20 + 20);
                formGraph5->DrawLine(Pens::Black, (ix - 1) * 20, (iy - 1) * 20 + 20, (ix - 1) * 20 + 20, (iy - 1) * 20);
                break;
            case 3:
                formGraph5->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black), (ix - 1) * 20 + 8, (iy - 1) * 20 + 8, 4, 4);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```